# How to mark template field marked as "acknowledged" in a gridview for asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
// html code  
<asp:GridView ID="DispatchDataGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" align="center" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RESOURCE_ID" HeaderText="Resource" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PARTICIPANT_NAME" HeaderText="Participant" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE_SENT" HeaderText="Date Sent" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TYPE" HeaderText="Type" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AMOUNT" HeaderText="Megawatts" DataFormatString="{0:00.00}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="STATE" HeaderText="State" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ACTIVE" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acknowlegdement" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="acknowledgestatus" runat="server"/>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="acknowledgement" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
```

I am looking to use the 'acknowledgement' template field as a way to keep track of a way a record as been acknowledged after users the button below the GV. Any help on how i should start this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I cant say ive gotten terribly far at all. I had an idea of assigning the current records as assigned, and then from then on checking if they are a certain type and marking them as acknowledged after the have been 'acknowledged'. Im just stuck on how to start the syntax for assigning the gridview rows values on load and after an acknowledgement

Comment: Start with binding the item template to your data source field like this `<asp:Label ID="acknowledgestatus" Text='<%# Eval("YourAcknowledgeStatusFieldName")%>' ...`

Comment: Oh okay, this wont work without actually having an official DB to bind it to will it? because i was hoping to accomplish this read status with just the template field.